# Error running lib/gdbserver: couldn't reserve 655360 bytes of adresse space at 0x8000 for "/data/app/com.embarcadero.Project2..."

Tags: android, delphi, android-emulator, firemonkey

I get this error while trying to run an android app in an Android Emulator created with Android Studio.

Any help please ?

Error running lib/gdbserver: couldn't reserve 655360 bytes of adresse space at 0x8000 for "/data/app/com.embarcadero.Project2..."

See the screenshot : [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMb3t.png)

Delphi 11.2 Architect edition.
Android Studio Dolphin - 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Same error for release or debug mode when using Android Emulator.
No error when running the same app on a USB connected device.
The version is the same on the Android Emulator version and the USB connected phone (Android 9).

Comment: Welcome! Could you please [read about why 'Can somebody help me?' is not really a question by our community's standards](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541) and [edit] to apply what you learn to ask your question? You can also see [ask] for further guidance. For example, a better question might look like: "_What is the cause of <specific issue>, and how can the problem be resolved to get <specific correct behaviour>?_"

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest ?

Comment: Did you assign enough RAM to the Emulator? (More specifically: assign enough RAM to the virtual device)

Comment: Hi @Bosshoss, i'm a newbie in android so can you tell me please where could I find the AndroidManifest ?

Comment: Hi @mjn, I put 4go of RAM in the emulator and 512mb of VM memory. Nothing changed.

Comment: Can someone help please ? thanks in advance.